# In terraform, how to loop over a list of objects and update values?

Tags: terraform, devops, terragrunt

I will be providing values with terragrunt. The variable, push_subscriptions, is a list of maps and I want to modify the values of the map. For example, append a prefix to the push subscription name in place like so (within the main.tf):

```
push_subscriptions[index]['name']  = "$pbsb-push-${var.product_environment_code}-push_subscriptions[index]['name']"
```

main.tf

```
module "pubsub" {
  push_subscriptions   = var.push_subscriptions
}
```

terragrunt.hcl

```
include "product_vars" {
  path = find_in_parent_folders("_terragrunt.hcl")
}

inputs = {

  push_subscriptions = [
    {
      name                       = "push-sub-1"                    
      ack_deadline_seconds       = 20                            
      push_endpoint              = "https://example.com"        
     },
    {
      name                       = "push-sub-2"                    
      ack_deadline_seconds       = 20                            
      push_endpoint              = "https://example.com"        
     }
   ]

}
```

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible in terraform. Not sure about terragrunt though.

Comment: You would need to construct a new map with the modified values. Value reassignment is not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't be a problem. Just create a local where you'll be using it, that iterates over the list and returns another list of objects with the updated values.

In this example, `local.subs` is used in lieu of your variable, but you would just replace `local.subs` with `var.push_subscriptions` in your case.

```
locals {
  subs = [
    { name = "foo" },
    { name = "bar" },
  ]

  updated = [for sub in local.subs : { name = "some-prefix-${sub.name}" }]
}

output "updated" {
  value = local.updated
}
```

Which gives:

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + updated = [
      + {
          + name = "some-prefix-foo"
        },
      + {
          + name = "some-prefix-bar"
        },
    ]
```

So that is a new value you can use with prefixes.

---

Or you could do this entirely in line, with something like:

```
module "pubsub" {
  push_subscriptions = [for sub in var.push_subscriptions : merge(sub, {
    name = "pbsb-push-${var.product_environment_code}-some-prefix-${sub.name}"
  })]
}
```

Using [merge](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/merge) here allows you to maintain all the other values.

Comment: thanks for the examples! In the last example, is that going to keep all the other fields in the map?
terraform needs a better console to play around in...

Comment: No it won't, that is just an example. If you want to keep all the other fields, you need to merge. I'll have updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Ahhh yes that’s a good way, I’ve merged but not in the loop like that. Thanks!!